# how to evaluate the accuracy of generated pictures by Generative adversarial network (GANs)?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, handwriting-recognition

i am stuck with this problem. I have generated handwritten digit using GANs. And now I want to evaluate how accurate my generated handwritten digits are. Is there any way??

Answer (score 2):

The most common ways to evaluate the network is to either show the visual output as in the original gan paper (http://papers.nips.cc/paper/5423-generative-adversarial-nets) or by showing on how well they do for semi-supervised learning (http://papers.nips.cc/paper/6125-improved-techniques-for-training-gans.pdf). This means using GANs to improve classification performance for the case, where only little data is available .